# Objective-C usage of exceptions

Tags: objective-c, exception

Exception are used for programmers faults only. So far so good, but what is this:

One of my classes is a simple XML-parser, which parses given xml (or parts of a xml). All methods are specialized for just one functional case. The may be, to find the only xml-element of class `xy`.

Even, if this case doesn't make sense if there are less or more `xy`-elements, I test, if there is really exactly one. Every other number of elements could nor be handled by my app (but the called api may change in future).

Is this a case, where exceptions are the preferred way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're using the parser for, if processing an xml with more than `xy` elements is something that's possible (because the producer could generate xml with more elements), I wouldn't consider it as an exception, and I would eventually return an error code.

Instead, if by specs the xml producer always generates an xml with only one xy element, then I would consider that as an exceptional case, hence I would raise an exception.

Comparison: if I have to process apples, and the input can be any fruit, then I wouldn't throw an exception every time I receive something that's not an apple. If instead I have to process apples, and the input can be apples only, then I would raise an exception if I find an apricot.

Comment: OK. Nice explanation :-) Then my feeling was right and exceptions are the way to go.